# Batch Error: “( was not expected at this time”

Tags: batch-file, cmd, unexpected-token

I'm doing a batch file to compile some dll, and well I have stuck on a simple but undetectable error...

Well, this is simple, I can't figure out why CMD is giving me this error, there is my code:

```
@echo off
::Call this in case your broke you dll and you cannot start Unity for example

:str
cls
goto :main

:main
echo Hello, well, if you're opening this is because you have done something wrong and you cannot start Unity...
echo.
set /p opt="Do you want to read your path from the 'path.txt' file or do you want to specify? [Y/N] "
echo.
echo Also, this is optional but you can try to establish an order for the compilation.
echo.
echo 1.- Build the API
echo 2.- Build the RAW Scripts
echo 3.- Build the Editor API
echo.
set /p order="Type, for example: [2 1 3], to compile in this order, or the way you want: "

if /i "%opt%" == "Y" (
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ("project_path.txt") do (
        if "%%f" NEQ "" (
            call :callcompile "%%f" "%order%"
        )
    )
) else (
    if /i "%opt%" == "N" (
        echo.
        set /p cpath="Path: "
        goto :callcompile "%cpath%" "%order%"
    ) else (
        goto :str
    )
)
goto :EOF

:callcompile
cmd /c compile.bat "%~1" "%~2"
pause
```

Maybe, I'm missing something, but I can't see any fail in my code, maybe because of my inexperience, anyway, help me to solve it, because I have enclosed all the conditions and everything that could be causing a trouble without luck.

All the source can be seen here: https://github.com/Lerp2Dev/Lerp2API/blob/master/Compile/emergency_case.bat

Also, is there anyway to see the exact line where the error is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes you can most likely see where the the error is.  Remove the `@echo off`, open up a cmd prompt and execute your batch file from the cmd prompt instead of double clicking it with your mouse.

Comment: You can't use a `GOTO` like this: `goto :callcompile "%cpath%" "%order%"`.  You are not passing anything to your subroutine.  Also your cpath variable has to be referenced with delayed expansion.

Comment: This what the script returned to me doing what you suggested @Squashman : http://pastebin.com/DkB2RsZv

Comment: Instead of `goto :callcompile "%cpath%" "%order%"` try `call :callcompile "%%cpath%%" "%order%"`.

Comment: The same happens @Compo thanks.

Comment: It was additional advice only, _a fix would have appeared as an answer not a comment_.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not thrown by `compile.bat`? There are several issues pointed out by the comments above, but none seems to explain the error message you are describing...

Comment: @aschipfl I think so... I will check why this is giving me an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tested your code but at first sight it seems you have two syntax errors.

The first error is about the `GoTo` statement, which only accepts one parameter, the label/sub-routine name, but you are trying to pass more than one parameter. Instead of `GoTo` you can use `Call`, or set/save the parameters into variables then call `GoTo` only passing the label name and finally read the parameter values from your variables.

The second error, would be because you are not enclosing the CMD argument with quotes.

The right syntax to call the CMD as you want, would be like this:

```
CMD.exe /C "argument"
```

where in case of that you pass in an argument that represents a command that takes additional arguments that contains whitespaces, then they must be enclosed too, like this:

```
CMD.exe /C " script.bat "C:\path with spaces" "
```

Or also:

```
CMD.exe /C " Start /W "" "script.bat" "C:\path with spaces" "
```

So try like this:

```
CMD.exe /C " "compile.bat" "%~1" "%~2" "
```